# Flutter not a Firebase error even though I have set up a catch error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I've made a login and sign in page in flutter and while using firebase when I try to login it catches error fine but when I sign up or create a user with the same error handling, it fails to catch the error and freezes the app and takes me to a firebase exception file. heres a video to show what I'm saying:

https://youtu.be/Tk5UgwSe9z4

here is the function:

### signUserUp()

```dart
void signUserUp(String email, String password, BuildContext context) {
  FirebaseAuth.instance
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
      .then((value) => Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, CustomPageRoute(child: const Home())))
      .catchError((error) {
    String errorMessage;
    if (error is FirebaseAuthException) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'network-error':
          errorMessage = 'Network error occured';
          break;
        case 'invalid-email':
          errorMessage = 'The email address is not valid';
          break;
        case 'user-disabled':
          errorMessage = 'The user account has been disabled';
          break;
        case 'user-not-found':
          errorMessage = 'No User Found';
          break;
        case 'wrong-password':
          errorMessage = 'The password is not correct';
          break;
        default:
          errorMessage = error.message ?? 'An unknown error occurred';
      }
    } else {
      errorMessage = error.toString();
    }
  });
}
// Then I use the "showDialog()" function to show a dialog box with the "errorMessage"
```

I tried to keep the question as clean as possible, please let me know if i need to provide any additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<void> signUserUp(String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, CustomPageRoute(child: const Home()));
  } catch (error) {
    String errorMessage;
    if (error is FirebaseAuthException) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'email-already-in-use':
          errorMessage = 'The email address is already in use by another account';
          break;
        case 'weak-password':
          errorMessage = 'The password is too weak';
          break;
        // ... Add other error cases related to sign-up as necessary
        default:
          errorMessage = error.message ?? 'An unknown error occurred';
      }
    } else {
      errorMessage = error.toString();
    }
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Error'),
          content: Text(errorMessage),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Close'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Some points to consider:

I changed the function to be async.
Errors thrown inside the try block will be caught by the catch block.
I added some additional error codes related to sign-up (e.g., email-already-in-use and weak-password), but you might want to add more based on Firebase documentation.
The showDialog() function is called inside the catch block, ensuring it's invoked when an error occurs.
If after these changes, you're still facing issues, you might want to debug further:

Check if there's any error in other parts of your code, especially before/after the call to signUserUp().
Ensure that your Firebase project is correctly set up for authentication, especially with email/password method.
Ensure that the dependencies in your pubspec.yaml are up-to-date and compatible.